# using xml layout and calling it in java code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have created how I want part of my app to look with 3 xml layout files and Im wondering how I can use it with my java UI code (the java code is an IMGUI code). I am trying to figure out how I can use my xml layout to put my java UI code in the red space (as show in the image) ...

[image]

The main xml is below.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/bar_color">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/activated_btn_color"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/activated_btn_color">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/brighness_icon"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:tint="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/btn_txt"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I did try this in java, however its just placing the IMGUI View inside a relative layout, which I guess it fine, but how can I put inside the red space in my xml drawing above?

```
 RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
 myLayout.addView(myIMGUI);
```

Do I have to code everything I did in xml in java to make this work?

Hopefully it makes sense what I am asking :)

Thank you!!